# Will the French Consulate ring my work place? (Visa)

Tags: france, australian-citizens

I am an Australian citizen living in Australia applying for a French Visa. It is a work visa, irrelevant which one. During my application process I must provide a phone contact from my current employment. My question is **will the French consulate in Sydney actually contact my work place**?? Has this happened to anyone?

Comment: I've removed the image because it didn't seem to relate to the question.

Comment: What kind of visa? Most Australians who come to France do so without visa, just a stamp in the passport on arrival.

Comment: @Willeke it seems likely to be a work visa, which could be the reason for the concern, especially if the visa applicant has not yet told the employer about his or her impending departure.

Comment: That is why I ask, as a work visa should be more at home on Expatriates.

Comment: As it's a work visa, this question is better suited to [Expatriates.SE].  And it may not be irrelevant which work visa you're applying for: it's entirely possible that French authorities investigate applicants for some categories of visa more closely than others.

Comment: I find it highly unlikely due to the language barrier. Very few French government employees speak English even in the immigration services.

Comment: @gstorto but those posted to consular missions in English speaking countries will indeed speak English.  Consulates also typically employ local staff, too.

Comment: @phoog my French work visa was processed in France, but I was sponsored. His case seems to be different though.

Comment: No they won't, i have had 2 work visas from france and in the 2 times they didnt

Comment: So the consensus is *they might.*